# Understanding Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

As I understand the term, "taxonomy" is just a way to group your posts, like "products." You can indicate your post is  a "product" by specifying "product" as a taxonomy of the post in wp_insert_post().  But you could also just add a custom field to the post, like "group=product" and then to pull all the *product* posts, ask for all the records that had a custom field of group=product.   I'm assuming, though,  that the latter method would require WordPress to look through all the posts for those that had a custom field of *group* whose value was *product*, while the taxonomy method essentially threads all the records together that have the taxonomy "product" so they're accessed directly instead of through a search through every post.  Is that correct?

Second, is "category" a built  in taxonomy?  So that if I assign a category of "product" when I do my wp_insert_post() then when I ask for all records with category =product,  will  WordPress  be able to access all the *product* posts directly, i.e., all the posts with category=product?

Comment: Yes, wordpress would be able to fetch all posts correctly,. 
Categories are attached to post.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can understand it well by studying following related tables:

- wp_terms
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_term_relationships

**wp_terms**:

It's most notable columns are `term_id`, `name`, and `slug`.

As the word implies, term is a really a name of something. For example for a league of football teams, a term would be the name of specific team in that league. Let's use `Foo` as the team name.

And as you may already know - each name will have a slug and an ID in order to easy common programming tasks relate to managing those terms.

**wp_term_taxonomy**:

Let's at the name of the table, you can guess that this table relates terms to taxonomies. The table's major columns are `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_id`, `taxonomy`, and `taxonomy_description`.

This table is actually grouping collection of terms together and give them a taxonomy (i.e categorizes them). Since `Foo` is a term and this term is a football team, it's appropriate that we categorize with something such as `football-team`.

`Bar` could be a different team name (another term). We can group/categorize both `Foo` and `Bar` as football teams, such that they both have the taxonomy/category `football-teams`. And of course, there's a description for each taxonomy to explain what this category is.

Note that each relationship we created have a unique ID that is term_taxonomy_id, so the relationship `Foo` and `football-team` have a unique ID. So does `Bar` and `football-team`. This will be important put into consideration when we view the next table.

**wp_term_relationships**:

Major columns are `object_id` and `term_taxonomy_id`. Which is basically a relationship between each `object_id` (a post ID for example) and an **ID of a relationship** between a term and a taxonomy/category.

So a post would have a `term_taxonomy_id` to tell us what term is representing this post (could be a post about team `Foo`) and of what category is this term (`football-team`).

When you consider the explanation above and take a look at the codex for [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), especially this part:

> **post_category:** Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_categories().
>
> **tags_input:** Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_tags().
>
> **tax_input:** Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_terms() for each custom taxonomy in the array. If the current user doesn't have the capability to work with a taxonomy, then you must use wp_set_object_terms() instead.

You will be able to understand how WordPress taxonomies work and answer your own questions.